# PHP: extract version number for string

Tags: php

I get each time different string.

From the string i need to extract the version number. when the version number can come in different types like:

```
v1.3
V1.3
v 2.4.1
V 2.4.1

version1.3
version 1.3
Version2.4.1
Version 2.4.1
```

The output need to be: `1.3 or 2.4.1`

**one more problem is that string can contain numbers beside the version number.**

what will be the fast way to do this task?

Comment: Use Regex to strip everything except 0-9 and "." from the string. Google Regex for more info.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Hi,
one more problem is that string can contain numbers beside the version number.

Comment: @user2413244 Check out whether my post is working fine?

Comment: @Sahil.Gulati, if that's the case, you need to provide examples of ones that have numbers that are not part of the version number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use regex for this:

Code:

```
<?php

function getVersion($str) {
    preg_match("/(?:version|v)\s*((?:[0-9]+\.?)+)/i", $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

print_r(getVersion("Version 2.4.1"));

?>
```

Regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/6WnQKt/3

Comment: Hi. thanks for the example. but as i edit my question: one more problem is that string can contain numbers beside the version number which i don't need.

Comment: your code return v1.3 and not 1.3. i have checked now.

Comment: Are you using the second index? [1]?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `preg_match` to do this. This will match any versions that are at the end of the string. Regex is `/(\d+\.?)+$/`.

```
$versions = array(
    'v1.3',
    'V1.3',
    'v 2.4.1',
    'V 2.4.1',
    'version1.3',
    'version 1.3',
    'Version2.4.1',
    'Version 2.4.1',
);

foreach($versions as $version) {
    if (0 !== preg_match('/(\d+\.?)+$/', $version, $matches)) {
        echo 'original: ' . $version . '; extracted: ' . $matches[0] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

> output

```
original: v1.3; extracted: 1.3
original: V1.3; extracted: 1.3
original: v 2.4.1; extracted: 2.4.1
original: V 2.4.1; extracted: 2.4.1
original: version1.3; extracted: 1.3
original: version 1.3; extracted: 1.3
original: Version2.4.1; extracted: 2.4.1
original: Version 2.4.1; extracted: 2.4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

[**PHP code demo**](https://regex101.com/r/O1rwXG/1)

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
$versions=array(
"v1.3",
"V1.3",
"v 2.4.1",
"V 2.4.1",
"version1.3",
"version 1.3",
"Version2.4.1",
"Version 2.4.1");

foreach($versions as $version)
{
    preg_match("/[vV](?:ersion)?\s*\K[\d\.]+/", $version,$matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1.3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2.4.1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2.4.1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1.3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2.4.1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2.4.1
)
```